# Concurrency issue with jta-jpa-pessmistic-write

Tags: hibernate, concurrency, ejb, eclipselink, jta

I am using Glassfish v4 and EJB application with JPA2.1(EclipseLink). I am having a concurrency issue with JTA. Basically, I am trying to lookup an entity by a given name, and then update a column with a new nextVal. 
So an EJB Stateless Bean

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "db")
private EntityManager em;

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public List<Long> getWithWriteLock(final String name, final int size) {
    TypedQuery<Sequence> q = em.createNamedQuery("Example.findByName", Example.class);
    q.setParameter("name", name);
    q.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    Example example = q.getSingleResult();
    final Long result = example.getNextval().longValue();
    final Long nextVal = result + size;
    final List<Long> resultList = LongStream.range(result, nextVal).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    example.setNextval(BigInteger.valueOf(nextVal));
    em.merge(example);
    em.flush(); //forced flush
    return resultList;
}
```

Application is deployed on multiple nodes and this method is assessed via an EJB Singleton with WRITE lock. What we see is that the list returned is duplicate random times. It even happens when different threads call this method even more than a minute apart. We have tried with explicit flush, merge and even verified that SQL logs that indeed use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE statement.
If anyone has seen something like this, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What is 'flush()' doing exactly? Shouldn't it be em.flush()?  Also, why are you using a hw2EntityManager instance to create the query when you are using em.merge later on - they should be the same EntityManager or your read is occurring in a different context.

Comment: yeah, its em.flush(). i updated my sample snippet. em context is also same.

Comment: You would have to check the logs, as this might occur if one transaction rolled back. JPA logging should show the values you are updating the objects with, and so allow you to trace which other thread put in those same values, and give a clue to why there were duplicates processed.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. So we have confirmed that there is no exception and this method is in new transaction, so even if caller transaction got rolled back, this will still go through. SQL logs say that we do a proper SELCT For update and then update nextVal to 'X' correctly only once. However the issue seems that 2 threads are calling the same method at the same time and they both get the copy of data same time, and the final List<Long> result is same. We are invoking this method from a Singleton with WRITE lock. Any thoughts?

Comment: Pessimistic locks rely on the database to work, and looks like yours is allowing the second query to return instead of waiting.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your help in this, really appreciate it! We are using MySQL. Do you have any suggestions on how else we can try this?

Comment: You will have to check your database settings - maybe try using these statements on the database directly to see what might be going wrong.

Comment: Does your `Sequence` object have a version field annotated with [@javax.persistence.Version](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Version.html)?

Comment: @SteveC No, the entity is not having version as we are using pessimistic locking for this one.

Comment: What transaction isolation level is your database connection using?

Comment: @SteveC We use default level.

Comment: That does not answer the question

Comment: @Chris From mysql logs I can see below.
select @@session.tx_read_only. I do notice that when first thread completes, mysql successfully updated and also committed the transaction. For the 2nd thread, it does a SELECT.. FOR UPDATE, however it did not issue the UPDATE sql and also does a XA rollback. This rollback is not thrown by JPA, so we are not able to catch it too and does not show up in our server logs.

Comment: That explains how you are reading the same value twice, but it is strange that it isn't logging anything in the server and you aren't seeing an exception. You will have to check all your exception handling everywhere in the application that might catch and ignore this. If the transaction is rolling back, that would explain why JPA doesn't issue the update (which would get rolled back anyway), as this happens in a pre-commit transaction event.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris. Yeah its a weird weird JTA/JPA bug it seems which is not propagating the XA rollback. Even if the parent transaction rollsback, child transaction if its new(in this case), it should succeed or rollback. We are not seeing anything in this case that JTA rollback happened and our application thinks its all good. So we end up with duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into EclipseLink's caching.

You should disable caching for this entity:

```
@Cacheable(false)
@Entity
public class Example {
     ...
}
```

See also [EclipseLink/FAQ/How to disable the shared cache?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F)

Comment: Its not that since we have that already and we also tried the exact same method by turning named query to native query to rule out any JPA cache and also modified named query to add EclipseLink hints to bypass cache, refresh etc.

Answer (score 0):

EJB Singleton only works in a single jvm, In multi nodes 
environment, you have to rely on the lock of your database. 
Don't use `REQUIRES_NEW`, use it only when you have to. Rollback happend in the `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction will not effect the outer transaction if there is a outer transaction. Because they are different transaction. The application stop the outer transaction and begin and commit or rollback the inner transaction, then resume the outer transaction.

Comment: Yes I know. However, Singleton is not there for the pessimistic lock. For that we have to depend on DB however, DB is issuing a XA rollback and its just that EJB is not catching that. So our app has no way to know the update never happened and it causes duplicate list to be returned in our app.